# unexpected error message using the cencorreg R function (NADA2)

Tags: r

I am trying to check whether a left censored variable (metal concentration in fish named met in the dataframe) is explained by different factors (age, gender and sampling area). For this purpose, I use the cencorreg function from the package NADA2. I attach below a repatable example. The cens column indicates whether the met values are below (TRUE) or above (FALSE) the detection limit.
I use R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt) - Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

```
# My dataframe
dfr <-
  structure(list(cens = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE,FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE,                          FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,                      FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                          FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
                          TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                          FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
                          TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
                 met = c(0.770, 1.147, 0.278,0.172, 0.136, 0.567,0.2614, 0.1749, 0.151, 1.7154, 
                         0.158, 1.532, 3.758, 2.634, 0.606,8.216, 0.184, 17.517, 2.046, 
                         0.151, 0.2326, 2.7239, 0.948,2.947, 0.147, 0.265, 
                         0.304, 0.147, 0.146, 0.134, 0.22, 0.816, 0.140, 
                         0.158, 0.154, 3.854, 0.157, 0.129, 0.355,2.125, 0.332, 0.165, 0.159, 0.148, 
                         0.125, 0.114, 0.144, 0.2574, 0.170,0.11, 0.805, 0.324, 2.852, 
                         0.841, 0.265, 0.237,0.349, 1.921, 0.394, 0.299, 
                         3.829, 0.122, 0.105, 0.482, 0.141,0.365, 0.108, 0.639, 0.327, 
                         0.296, 0.197, 0.316, 0.116), 
                 age = c("yo", "ad", "subad", "ad", "yo", "ad", "subad", 
                            "yo", "yo", "subad", "yo", "yo", "yo", "subad", "yo", "subad", 
                            "yo", "yo", "yo", "ad", "ad", "subad", "ad", "subad", "yo", 
                            "subad", "subad", "yo", "yo", "yo", "yo", "yo", "yo", "yo", 
                            "yo", "yo", "subad", "yo", "ad", "subad", "ad", "yo", "yo", 
                            "yo", "yo", "ad", "ad", "yo", "yo", "ad", "subad", "subad", 
                            "ad", "ad", "ad", "ad", "ad", "subad", "ad", "ad", "subad", 
                            "ad", "ad", "ad", "ad", "subad", "subad", "ad", "subad", 
                            "subad", "ad", "subad", "ad"), 
                 gend = c("f", "f", "f", "f",
                          "m", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", 
                            "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", 
                           "f", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "f", 
                           "m", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", 
                            "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "f", 
                            "f", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "f"), 
                 area = c("A","B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B",
                          "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", 
                           "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
                           "C", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B", "A", 
                           "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
                           "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A")), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -73L))


# Analysis using cencorreg
library(NADA2)
cencorreg(dfr$met,dfr$cens,dfr[, c("age","gend","area")]) 
cencorreg(dfr$met,dfr$cens,dfr[, c("age","gend")]) 
cencorreg(dfr$met,dfr$cens,dfr[, c("age","area")])
cencorreg(dfr$met,dfr$cens,dfr$age) # I get an error message "Error in log(nonas[, 1]) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function"
cencorreg(dfr$met,dfr$cens,dfr[, c("age")])# I get an error message "Error in log(nonas[, 1]) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function"
cencorreg(dfr$met,dfr$cens,dfr$gend) # I get an error message "Error in log(nonas[, 1]) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function"
```

I do not understand why the cencorreg with only one factor don't work while it is not the case when two factors or more are included. It seems that nonas[, 1] is considered as a non-numeric argument in the last 3 cencorreg (thus impossible to log-transformed y) but it is not the case in the 3 first ones?

Please, if you have any comments that can help me. Thanks in advance

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Your post was duplicated [here](https://github.com/SwampThingPaul/NADA2/issues/6) in the R-package GitHub page. We updated the `cencorreg(...)` function in the development version (ie GitHub) of the package and are expecting to submit this version to CRAN soon.

Answer (score 0):

One of the primary issues was that the explanatory variables must be input as a data frame, not just as a cbind matrix.  We will make that more explicit in the metatext.